# How to unhide contact?

Tags: google-hangouts

I've hidden contact in hangouts' dialog for opening new hangout, by clicking on one of icons of most frequent contacts, then in "Contact options"->"Hide contact":

[image]

Now I wonder how to "unhide" it?

(Notes: Currently using "Hangouts Version 2.1.100 (1151589-30)")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved with **Hangouts version 2.1.223**. 
In "settings" we now have an option do "unhide" contacts.
Thanks Google.

Answer (score 0):

If you have hidden any contact and now want to unhide, just see at the top, next to notification bar, you will find a dotted sqaure box which contain folders liek "My Accounts, Search, Map etc". Now see at the bottom, you will find option of more. Click on it. Now there you will find "Hangout" folder. Click on it. Once you click it, a handout page will get opened. Now at the extreme left, you will find "Menu, then at bottom you will find Contact, Conversation, Phone Calls, More". Click on "More". After that at the bottom, you would find "Settings option". Now in that you will find A box like "Share your status" and all. Again go at bottom, you will find "Hidden Contact". Go on it and you will find hidden contacts and now you can unhide whom you want. All the best.

Answer (score -1):

If you have the contact in your contact lists then just type the name in search bar.

Comment: That's what we do. However, so far earlier hidden contact does not appear in top icons, faces even frequently used, will it? (To make it clear: even I hangout with Joe Doe, he does not appear on list "people you hangout with" after I selected him as "Hide contact". Therefore I wonder if it's question of time or if Joe Doe is permamently hidden, if so - how to unhide him?)

Answer (score -1):

Go to settings page and select the account where you want to unhide the contact. Scroll down, you will find the hidden contacts option.

Answer (score -1):

*On Hangout version 8.0.11.*
Hidden contact is in the **Archived Conversations**.
You can find archive on your left screen - Hamburger menu.